# how do I do groups for unix commands

Tags: unix

I want do something like this:

```
python *.py > *.std
```

I tried doing:

```
python (*).py > \1.std
```

but that is wrong,

Answer (score 2):

You don't. You process them in a loop.

```
for f in *.py
do
  python "$f" > "${f%.py}".std
done
```